# Expo iOS failing build

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm currently working on a react-native app via Expo and am running into some issues when trying to view the app locally on iOS simulator. After running `npx expo run:ios`, I can see that the building is complete but I'm met with these two errors before the app can load in the simulator:

1. `TypeError: property is not configurable, js engine: hermes`

- according to the stacktrace, it looks like this error is occurring in the `expo-linking` package?

2. 

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^7.14.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "reanimated-color-picker": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

I've tried building the ios app via Expo with after cleaning cache but no luck. The app works just fine on android devices via Expo Go so I'm not really sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

This dependency was causing the error

```
"expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3"
```

The latest version of this dependency doesn't work well with Expo Go so I'll need to find an alternative.